# Flyway partial migration of legacy application

Tags: java, database-migration, flyway

In an application with a custom database migrator which we want to replace with Flyway.

These migrations are split into some categories like "account" for user management and "catalog" for the product catalog.
Files are named `$category.migration.$version.sql`. Here, `$category` is one of the above categories and `$version` is an integer version *starting from 0*.

e.g.  `account.migration.23.sql`

Although one could argue that each category should be a separate database, in fact it isn't and a major refactoring would be required to change that.

Also I could use one schema per category, but again this would require rewriting all SQL queries.

So I did the following:

- Move `$category.migration.$version.sql` to `/sql/$category/V$version__$category.sql` (e.g. `account.migration.1.sql` becomes `/sql/account/V1_account.sql`)
- Use a metadata table *per category*
- set the baseline version to zero

In code that would be

```java
String[] _categories = new String[] { "catalog", "account" };
for (String _category : _categories) {
  Flyway _flyway = new Flyway();
  _flyway.setDataSource(databaseUrl.getUrl(), databaseUrl.getUser(), databaseUrl.getPassword());
  _flyway.setBaselineVersion(MigrationVersion.fromVersion("0"));
  _flyway.setLocations("classpath:/sql/" + applicationName);
  _flyway.setTarget(MigrationVersion.fromVersion(_version + ""));

  _flyway.setTable(category + "_schema_version");
  _flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true); // (1)
  _flyway.migrate();
}
```

So there would be the metadata tables `catalog_schema_version` and `account_schema_version`.

Now the issue is as follows:
Starting with an empty database I would like to apply all pre-existing migrations per category, as done above.
If I remove `_flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);` (1), then the `catalog` migration (the first one) succeeds, but it would complain for `account` that the schema `public` is not empty.

Likewise setting `_flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);` causes the following behavior:
The migration of "catalog" succeeds but `V0_account.sql` is ignored and Flyway starts with `V1_account.sql`, maybe because it somehow still thinks the database was already baselined?

Does anyone have a a suggestion for resolving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest solution is to keep the `schema_version` tables in another schema each. I've answered a [very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240560/369930).

Regarding your observation on `baseline`, those are expected traits. The migration of `account` starts at `v1` because with the combination of `baseline=0`, `baselineOnMigrate=true` and a non empty target schema (because `catalog` has populated it) Flyway has determined this is a pre-existing database that is equal to the baseline - thus start at `v1`.

Comment: This behavior really confused me, I'll see that the docs are updated accordingly.